# Iterate over json on sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I'm working with on a project that has a questionnaire in it.
I'm using Python, Flask, Postgres and Sqlalchemy.

I need to build a search endpoint that filters the documents by the title **or** by any of the answers in the questionnaire.

The database is structured the following way:

[Client] - One to Many - [Document] - One to Many - [DocumentVersion]

So that one Client can have many Documents and each document may have many Document Versions.

```
### DocumentVersion Model

class DocumentVersion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'document_version'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('document.id'), nullable=False)
    answers = db.Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    # ... other columns
    document = relationship('Document', back_populates='versions')

@hybrid_method
def answers_contain(self, text):
    '''returns True if the text appears in any of the answers'''
    contains_text = False
    for answer in self.answers:
        if text == str(answer['answer'].astext):
            contains_text = True
            
    return contains_text
```

Inside the [DocumentVersion] table, there is a JSONB field storing the questions and the answers.
The json is structured the following way:

```
[{
    "value": "question"
    "answer": "foo",
    ...
},
{
    "value": "question"
    "answer": "bar",
    ...
},
...
]
```

The filter document by document title is working fine, but I can't figure out a way to filter by the answers in the json.

I believe I have to iterate over the json to make the filter. So I tried to create a **@hybrid_method** called `answers_contain` to do so,
but when I do `for answer in self.answers` in the hydrid method, the loop actually never ends. I wonder if it's possible to iterate over the json
while making the query. If I try `len(self.answers)` inside the hybrid method, I get a
`TypeError: object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len().`

```
### Search endpoint
try:
        page = int(request.args.get('page', 1))
        per_page = int(request.args.get('per_page', 20))
        search_param = str(request.args.get('search', ''))
    except:
        abort(400, "invalid parameters")

paginated_query = Document.query \
        .filter_by(client_id=current_user['client_id']) \
        .join(Document.versions) \
        .filter(or_(
            Document.title.ilike(f'%{search_param}%'),
            DocumentVersion.answers_contain(f'%{search_param}%'),
        )) \
        .order_by(desc(Document.created_at)) \
        .paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)
```

I also tried to filter like this:
`DocumentVersion.answers.ilike(f'%{search_param}%')`,  which gives me an error and a hint:
`HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` If I added explicit type casts I would have to hardcode the questions, but I can't, since they can change.

What is the best way to do this filtering? I'd like to avoid bringing all the client documents to the backend server, if possible.
Is there a way to iterate over the json while making the query, on the db server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: those answers look pretty structured. Why would you store structured data in SQL DB using JSON type?

Comment: There are also question specific properties in each object, including nestled objects, like possible answers. Also there are other parts of the program using it.